# How to display more carousels in one row?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-carousel

I want to build an image gallery. Each picture would represent set of images. I kind of realized that nice solution to that would be this: each image would trigger a modal, and inside of a modal I would put carousel where other images would be displayed. But I ran into a problem, I am not able to make carousels to work properly (they are embedded in one row). Please check jsfiddle for more info:   https://jsfiddle.net/r0ukv00d/4/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Eyjafjallaj%C3%B6kull.jpeg" height="42" width="42" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><h5>
        Click on the image and you will be able to see images from Iceland.
        </h5>
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                <!-- Indicators -->
                                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                    <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                    <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                    <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                </ol>
                                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                    <div class="item active"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Eyjafjallaj%C3%B6kull.jpeg" alt="...">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption"> Iceland1 </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item"> <img src="http://www.icelandprocruises.co.uk/media/img/gallery/home/0002-gallery-iceland-waterfall-1.jpg" alt="...">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">Iceland2 </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item"> <img src="http://querzy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/iceland.jpg" alt="...">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption"> Iceland3 </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Controls -->
                                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a>
                                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> <img src="https://cache-graphicslib.viator.com/graphicslib/thumbs360x240/16674/SITours/private-sugar-loaf-and-christ-the-redeemer-tour-in-rio-de-janeiro-278478.jpg" height="42" width="42" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <h5>
        Click on the image and you will be able to see images from Brazil.
        </h5>
        <h3 style="color:red">
       Second carousel is not working! It shows pictures from Iceland instead of Brazil!
        </h3>
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div id="carousel-2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                <!-- Indicators -->
                                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                    <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                    <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                    <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                </ol>
                                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                    <div class="item active"> <img src="https://cache-graphicslib.viator.com/graphicslib/thumbs360x240/16674/SITours/private-sugar-loaf-and-christ-the-redeemer-tour-in-rio-de-janeiro-278478.jpg" alt="...">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption"> Brazil1 </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item"> <img src="http://www.sportiputovanja.hr/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/RIO-BEACH.jpg" alt="...">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption"> Brazil2 </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item"> <img src="http://riotimesonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Fernando-Maia-Riotur.png" alt="...">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption"> Brazil3 </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Controls -->
                                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a>
                                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given below is modern way of doing it. You can refer [this link](http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) for further details of the way of creating modal dynamically. Else then that javascript code in either `message` or `msg` is done by me to dynamically generate everything so that if you have stored everything in database you just have to create a similar json there and parse it here and you are done. Adding and deleting images,country will also be easy will also be easy.

```js
var countryjson={
   
   list : [
    {
     name    : 'Iceland',
     img_path : 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Eyjafjallaj%C3%B6kull.jpeg',
     otherimages : [
      {
       image_path : 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Eyjafjallaj%C3%B6kull.jpeg',
       image_title: 'Title goes here.',
       image_caption : 'This is 1st image of iceland and this is its caption',
      },
      {
       image_path : 'http://www.icelandprocruises.co.uk/media/img/gallery/home/0002-gallery-iceland-waterfall-1.jpg',
       image_title: 'Title goes here.',
       image_caption : 'This is 2nd image of iceland and this is its caption',
      },
      {
       image_path : 'http://querzy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/iceland.jpg',
       image_title: 'Title goes here.',
       image_caption : 'This is 3rd image of iceland and this is its caption',
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     name    : 'Brazil',
     img_path : 'https://cache-graphicslib.viator.com/graphicslib/thumbs360x240/16674/SITours/private-sugar-loaf-and-christ-the-redeemer-tour-in-rio-de-janeiro-278478.jpg',
     otherimages : [
      {
       image_path : 'https://cache-graphicslib.viator.com/graphicslib/thumbs360x240/16674/SITours/private-sugar-loaf-and-christ-the-redeemer-tour-in-rio-de-janeiro-278478.jpg',
       image_title: 'Title goes here.',
       image_caption : 'This is 1st image of iceland and this is its caption',
      },
      {
       image_path : 'http://www.sportiputovanja.hr/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/RIO-BEACH.jpg',
       image_title: 'Title goes here.',
       image_caption : 'This is 2nd image of iceland and this is its caption',
      },
      {
       image_path : 'http://riotimesonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Fernando-Maia-Riotur.png',
       image_title: 'Title goes here.',
       image_caption : 'This is 3rd image of iceland and this is its caption',
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
   
   
   
  }
  
  
  function loadCountries()
  {
  
   for(i=0;i<countryjson.list.length;i++)
   {
    var countrybean=countryjson.list[i];
    
    var msg='';
    msg+='<div class="col-sm-3">';
    msg+=' <div class="panel panel-default" onclick="showModal('+i+')">';
    msg+='  <div class="panel-body">';
    msg+='   <img src="'+countrybean.img_path+'" class="adjust-img" alt="'+countrybean.name+' Image">';
    msg+='  </div>';
    msg+='  <div class="panel-footer" align="center">'+countrybean.name+'</div>';
    msg+=' </div>';
    msg+='</div>';
    
    $('#country_list').append(msg);
    
   }
  }
  
  
  function showModal(country_id){
  
   BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'Other images of '+countryjson.list[country_id].name,
    message: function(dialog) {
     
     var message ='';
     var ol_list='';
     var image_list='';
     var corosol_id='myCarousel_'+country_id;
     
     
     var countrybean=countryjson.list[country_id];
     
     for(i=0;i<countrybean.otherimages.length;i++)
     {
      var imagebean=countrybean.otherimages[i];
      ol_list+='<li data-target="#'+corosol_id+'" data-slide-to="'+i+'" '+ (i==0?'class="active"':'') +'></li>';
      image_list+='<div class="item '+ (i==0?'active':'') +'">';
      image_list+=' <img src="'+imagebean.image_path+'" alt="'+imagebean.image_title+'" >';
      image_list+=' <div class="carousel-caption">';
      image_list+='  <h3>'+imagebean.image_title+'</h3>';
      image_list+='  <p>'+imagebean.image_caption+'</p>';
      image_list+=' </div>';
      image_list+='</div>';
     }
     
     message+='<div id="'+corosol_id+'" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">';
     message+=' <!-- Indicators -->';
     message+=' <ol class="carousel-indicators">'+ol_list+'</ol>';
     
     message+=' <!-- Wrapper for slides -->';
     message+=' <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">'+image_list+'</div>';
     
     message+=' <!-- Left and right controls -->';
     message+=' <a class="left carousel-control" href="#'+corosol_id+'" role="button" data-slide="prev">';
     message+='  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
     message+='  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>';
     message+=' </a>';
     message+=' <a class="right carousel-control" href="#'+corosol_id+'" role="button" data-slide="next">';
     message+='  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
     message+='  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>';
     message+=' </a>';
     message+='</div>';
     
     return message;
    }
   });
  
  }
  
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
   loadCountries();
  });
```

```css
.adjust-img
  {
   width : 100%;
   height : 300px;
  }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div clas="rows" id="country_list">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is very neat! Thank you so much for replaying detailed, since database issue would be my next question anyway. I am going to try to implement it like this!

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the same model ID for both images. Please see https://jsfiddle.net/r0ukv00d/5/ for updated code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Eyjafjallaj%C3%B6kull.jpeg" height="42" width="42" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><h5>
        Click on the image and you will be able to see images from Iceland.
        </h5>
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                <!-- Indicators -->
                                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                    <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                    <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                    <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                </ol>
                                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                    <div class="item active"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Eyjafjallaj%C3%B6kull.jpeg" alt="...">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption"> Iceland1 </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item"> <img src="http://www.icelandprocruises.co.uk/media/img/gallery/home/0002-gallery-iceland-waterfall-1.jpg" alt="...">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption">Iceland2 </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item"> <img src="http://querzy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/iceland.jpg" alt="...">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption"> Iceland3 </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Controls -->
                                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a>
                                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> <img src="https://cache-graphicslib.viator.com/graphicslib/thumbs360x240/16674/SITours/private-sugar-loaf-and-christ-the-redeemer-tour-in-rio-de-janeiro-278478.jpg" height="42" width="42" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
        <h5>
        Click on the image and you will be able to see images from Brazil.
        </h5>
        <h3 style="color:red">
       Second carousel is not working! It shows pictures from Iceland instead of Brazil!
        </h3>
            <div id="myModal1" class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div id="carousel-2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                <!-- Indicators -->
                                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                    <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                    <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                    <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                </ol>
                                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                    <div class="item active"> <img src="https://cache-graphicslib.viator.com/graphicslib/thumbs360x240/16674/SITours/private-sugar-loaf-and-christ-the-redeemer-tour-in-rio-de-janeiro-278478.jpg" alt="...">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption"> Brazil1 </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item"> <img src="http://www.sportiputovanja.hr/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/RIO-BEACH.jpg" alt="...">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption"> Brazil2 </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item"> <img src="http://riotimesonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Fernando-Maia-Riotur.png" alt="...">
                                        <div class="carousel-caption"> Brazil3 </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Controls -->
                                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a>
                                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```