# carousel inside modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Good day, I'm trying to create simple image slideshow in carousel.But i facing a proble when i try to add this carousel inside modal. Here is my script

```
<div id="modalphoto" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-body">
             <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
                  <div class="carousel-inner">

                  </div>

            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

The trigger to show modal

```
<?php if(isset($photo)){ ?>
            <?php foreach($photo as $foto) { ?>
                  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                        <a class="thumbnail">
                            <p align="center">Item : (<?=$foto->ItemCode;?>)  <br>
                                <?=$foto->ItemName;?>
                                <input type="hidden" class="itemcodes" value="<?=$foto->ItemCode;?>">
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
        <?php } } ?>
```

and then my Javascript.

```
$(document).on("click",".thumb",function(){
            $('.carousel-inner').html("");
            var Items  = $(this).find('input:hidden').val();
                $.ajax({
                    data : {Items:Items},
                    url : '<?=base_url();?>Item/getphoto',
                    type:'POST',
                    datatype:'JSON',
                    success:function(data){
                           data = $.parseJSON(data);
                         $.each(data, function(k , v) { 
                            $(".carousel-inner").append('<div class="item">'+
                                                        '<img class="img-responsive" src="./assets/file_upload/md/'+v.PhotoName+'" style="width:100%">'+
                                                        '<div class="carousel-caption">'+v.ItemName+'</div></div>'
                                                        )

                        });
                        $("#modalphoto").modal("show");

                    }
                });
        });
```

the problem is when i click `.thumb` my screen goes black. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

How can i fix it?

sorry for my bad english. My Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/00113e4g/4/

Comment: Please create a JsFiddle for this issue

Comment: @RaviUbana https://jsfiddle.net/00113e4g/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your carousel-inner fragment is wrong.

Change it so that each element can be like:

```
<div class="item">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/365"
       style="width: 100%; height: auto">
   <div class="carousel-caption">acts_as_money</div>
</div>
```

Moreover, the first element needs the active class.

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var data = [{
        "ItemCode": "ANK160500191",
        "PhotoName": "1.png",
        "PhotoFlag": 1
    },
        {
            "ItemCode": "ANK160500191",
            "PhotoName": "BTY2.png",
            "PhotoFlag": 1
        }, {
            "ItemCode": "ANK160500191",
            "PhotoName": "fffff.png",
            "PhotoFlag": 1
        }, {
            "ItemCode": "ANK160500191",
            "PhotoName": "result.png",
            "PhotoFlag": 1
        }, {
            "ItemCode": "ANK160500191",
            "PhotoName": "SKSM2.png",
            "PhotoFlag": 1
        }];


    $(document).on("click", ".thumb", function() {
        $('.carousel-inner').html("");
        var Items = $(this).find('input:hidden').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.github.com/repositories?since=364",
            data: {
                Items: Items
            },
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                //data = $.parseJSON(data);
                $.each(data.slice(0,3), function(k, v) {
                    var act = (k == 0) ? 'active' : '';
                    $(".carousel-inner").append('<div class="item '  + act + '">' +
                            '<img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/'+v.id+'" style="width: 100%; height: auto">' +
                            '<div class="carousel-caption">' + v.name + '</div></div>'
                    )

                });
                $("#modalphoto").modal("show");

            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="modalphoto" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 1">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        Caption Slide 1
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 2">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        Caption Slide 2
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 3">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        Caption Slide 3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box-body table-responsive">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
        <a class="thumbnail">
            <p align="center">Item : (0019177)  <br>
                SANDAL 6170-23 BROWN <input type="hidden" class="itemcodes" value="0019177">
            </p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
        <a class="thumbnail">
            <p align="center">Item : (ANK160500191)  <br>
                NECKLACE  <input type="hidden" class="itemcodes" value="ANK160500191">
            </p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's show me the picture. I wonder, why the slideshow not working ?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42282183/3553316).

It has all the answer you needed. It even shows how you can display modal dynamically. Without even coding anything and just with calling function how can you display a modal is also shown here.