# for loop in document.getelementbyid

Tags: javascript, loops, bootstrap-modal

I want to loop the code below up to 50 times. How can I do this?

first

```
document.getElementById("myBtn_1").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("myModal_1").style.display = "block";
};

document.getElementsByClassName("close_1")[0].onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("myModal_1").style.display = "none";
};

window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == document.getElementById("myModal_1")) {
    document.getElementById("myModal_1").style.display = "none";
} };
```

second:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn_2").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("myModal_2").style.display = "block";
};


document.getElementsByClassName("close_2")[0].onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("myModal_2").style.display = "none";
};


window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == document.getElementById("myModal_2")) {
    document.getElementById("myModal_2").style.display = "none";
} };
```

I want to open this modal with php foreach. therefor I pass $count to the id´s.

thanks

Comment: Where is the PHP to support the PHP tag?

Comment: _I want to loop the code below up to 50 times_ **Up to 50 time??** Loops are normally very precise about how many times they iterate!!

Comment: Why you want to create 50 bootstrap modal in single page???
Isn't it better to create just one and change the content when needed???

Comment: You can also check ths link which may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275933/how-to-display-more-carousels-in-one-row/42282183#42282183

Answer (score 0):

You could change like this .`addEventListener()` is better with `Dom onclick`

```
for(var i=0; i<50; i++){
    document.getElementById("myBtn_"+i).addEventListener('click' ,function() {
        document.getElementById("myModal_"+i).style.display = "block";
    })

    document.getElementsByClassName("close_"+i)[0].addEventListener('click' ,function() {
        document.getElementById("myModal_"+i).style.display = "none";
    })
}

document.getElementById("myModal_1").addEventListener('click',function(){
    this.style.display = "none";//target element is `myModal_1` so direct apply with click with this element
})
```

Answer (score 0):

there is my php tag.
I hope you understand what I mean. The data from my database are output in a table. Now I would like to display the details with the help of a modal call.

```
...

<?php foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row)  { 
$count = $count + 1;  ?>
<tr>
<td>
<a id="myBtn_<?php echo $count; ?>"><li class="fa fa-search">&nbsp;</li></a>  
</td> 
</tr>

<div id="myModal_<?php echo $count; ?>" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close_<?php echo $count; ?>">&times;</span>
<p>first item from db</p>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```