# Modal disabling the page until refresh

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal which contains dynamic data generated from db. The problem is when i open a modal it disables whole screen until i refresh the page.Even i can't close my modal. Why is it so? I have added libraries at the end of the code also.

**Code**

```
   <?php
include "db.php";
?>
<head>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/animsition.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Theme styles -->
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->

    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="popular" class="tab-pane counties-pane active animated fadeIn">
    <?php
    $q=mysqli_query($con,"  SELECT c.* , sc.* , sm.* ,ca.* from store_category sc INNER JOIN store_manufacture sm ON sm.sm_id=sc.store_id INNER JOIN categories ca ON ca.cat_id=sc.cat_id INNER JOIN coupons c on c.c_sc_id=sc.sc_id ");
    while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($q,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $h = strpos($row1['sm_link'], 'http');
        ?>
        <!-- Large modal -->

        <div class="coupon-wrapper row">
            <div class="coupon-data col-sm-2 text-center">
                <div class="savings text-center">
                    <div>
                        <div class="large"><?php echo $row1['c_name'] ?></div>
                        <div class="small">off</div>
                        <div class="type"><?php echo $row1['sm_brand_name'] ?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end:Savings -->
            </div>
            <!-- end:Coupon data -->
            <div class="coupon-contain col-sm-7">

                <h4 class="coupon-title"><a href="<?php echo ($h !== FALSE)?$row1['sm_link']:"http://".$row1['sm_link'] ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $row1['c_description']?></a></h4>

                <p data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo $row1['c_id']?>">Shop these Shopname deals of the day  to save as much...</p>
                <p id="<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>" class="collapse">Don't miss out on all the coupon savings.Get you coupon now and save big</p>

                <!-- end:Coupon details -->
            </div>
            <!-- end:Coupon cont -->
            <div class="button-contain col-sm-3 text-center">

              <p class="btn-code" data-toggle="modal"  data-target=".couponModal<?php echo $row1['c_id']?>" data-id="<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>">
                    <span class="partial-code"><?php echo $row1['c_code'] ?></span>
                    <span class="btn-hover">Get Code</span></p>

            </div>

            <!-- end: coupon wrap -->
            <div class="coupon_modal modal fade couponModal<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  >
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="ti-close"></i></span> </button>
                        <div class="coupon_modal_content">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center">
                                    <h2><?php echo $row1['c_name'] ?></h2>
                                    <p><?php echo $row1['c_description'] ?></p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <h5 class="text-center text-uppercase m-t-20 text-muted">Click below to get your coupon code</h5>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3"> <a href="<?php echo ($h !== FALSE)?$row1['sm_link']:"http://".$row1['sm_link'] ?>" target="_blank" class="coupon_code alert alert-info"><span class="coupon_icon"><i class="ti-cut hidden-xs"></i></span>  <?php echo $row1['c_code'] ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end: Coupon modal content -->
                    </div>
                </div>





            </div>
           </div>


        <?php
    }
    ?>


</div>
    <!--modal-->

    <!--Modal-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/animsition.min.js"></script>
<script src="owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<!-- Kupon js -->
<!--<script src="assets/js/kupon.js"></script>-->


</body>
</html>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like your back drop of modal is getting more z-index then modal it self? is your data loaded perfectly in back ground?

Comment: I would start by putting the modal directly in the `<body>` tag, not somewhere inside other `<div>` tags.

Comment: @ShalinPatel ye it is. But when i open the modal it gets stuck

Comment: @KIKOSoftware why is it so?

Comment: @tabia Check if your bootstrap is loaded only once in the html. I experienced trouble with bootstrap when I accidentally load bootstrap multiple times. And the problems I face can only be resolved after refreshing.

Comment: @ErnestSoo you are talking about bootsrap links

Comment: @tabia: Read the manual: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals second point: "Always try to place a modal's HTML code in a top-level position in your document to avoid other components affecting the modal's appearance and/or functionality.".

Comment: can you put your full code here from which you are opening modal.

Comment: @ShalinPatel i have updated my code . Have a look

Comment: @ShalinPatel  have a look please

Comment: Rather then making it like this put all your data in a json array which contains every row as a bean and then get data from array while showing the screen.
You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42282183/3553316